# strtotime time/date in PHP switch/case statement

Tags: php

I've created a PHP `switch / case` statement:

```
switch(true)
{
    case ($eff >= '10/2017'):
        echo "Greater than 10-2017";
        break;
    case ($eff <= '09/2017'):
        echo "Less thank 10-2017";
        break;                          
    default:
        echo '';
        break;
}
```

I'm using `strtotime` to cut down a date from `08/01/2017` to just `08/2017` like this:

```
$eff = date("m/Y", strtotime($userinfo['ExpDate']));
```

Unfortunately when I use this to create my case statement it doesn't give me the conditional output. I was hoping for when using a `>` or `<` operator and just defaults to the first case statement.

How do I use this to properly use greater/less than?

Comment: Compare dates, not strings

Comment: @JohnConde I thought that was what I was doing

Comment: You can't compare it in this way because you don't compare dates rather than simple strings.

Comment: okay.. @Tyr suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a solution like the following:

```
<?php
$eff = date("m/Y", strtotime('10/01/2017'));
$eff = date_create_from_format('m/Y', $eff);

switch(true)
{
    case (date_create_from_format('m/Y', '10/2017')->diff($eff)->format('%R%m') >= 0):
        echo "Greater than 10-2017";
        break;
    case (date_create_from_format('m/Y', '09/2017')->diff($eff)->format('%R%m') <= 0):
        echo "Less thank 10-2017";
        break;                          
    default:
        echo '';
        break;
}
```

> **demo:** https://ideone.com/Z2un3C / **some tests:** https://3v4l.org/YP1Ub

Comment: Beautiful answer...this worked great.  Thanks so much.  I inserted my variable for the date and it worked awesome.  Thanks again!